# Straight lines forming an equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

I have the straight lines:

$$L1: (1, 0, 0) + r(1, 1, 1)$$
$$L2: (7, 4, 3) + s(3, 4, 2)$$

I'm asked to get the vertices of the equilateral triangle of side 2 * 2 ^ (1/2) so one vertex belongs to L2 and the opposite side is in L1.

I don't even know where to start.
I have some ideas though. I have 3 equal sides that form 60 degrees.
The vertex in L2 should should satisfy the parametric equations of L2:

$$x2 = 7 + 3s$$
$$y2 = 4 + 4s$$
$$z2 = 3 + 2s$$

The other 2 vertices should satisfy the parametric equations of L1:

$$x1 = 1 + r$$
$$y1 = r$$
$$z1 = r$$

Now the distance is 2 * 2 ^ (1/2).
What the next stop?
Working with the distance?
I tried that but I'm not going anywhere with that. I tried with distance between the vertex of L2 and 1 of the vertex in L1. I also tried the 2 on L2.

Thanks

Comment: You have an error in $L_2$ it should be $y_2=4+4s$ unless there is an error higher up.

Comment: You are right. I don't know where i got the 5. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Since you have three vertices, you should represent the third.  As it is on $L1$, it will be $x3=1+t,y3=t,z3=t$.  Now write the distance formulas:  One of them, from point $1$ to point $3$, is $((1+r)-(1+t))^2+(r-t)^2+(r-t)^2=(2\sqrt 2)^2=8$  This will give three equations in three unknowns.  WOLOG you can assume $r \gt t$.

Comment: I was trying something like that, but i noticed i did it with s. Thanks for the hint, ill work with it now.